# Tomcat allocates a new thread per HTTP request so what's the motivation of using future.get()?

Tags: java, tomcat, server, future, callable

I know tomcat server container, allocates a new thread for every new HTTP request.Then what's the motivation behind the use of callable + future?

1) Why do we care if the only thread for the current request is doing a long task?

2) If the main thread is blocked by future.get() then what's the saving over just letting it do the long taks? Is it about tomcat recognizing the thread is idle + blocked - so it knows not to raise a "timeout" flag?

3) What is the advantage of using while(future.isDone()) over just being blocked by future.get()? It's not like this thread can do something else while busy waiting.

Comment: In general, a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is not a useful tool for use in the request-processing thread of a Servlet container. If you want to improve the web server's handling of long-running requests, you should use the asynchronous processing features of the Servlet container, not a `Future`.

Comment: No, you don't know that. (1) Tomcat uses a thread pool, so it isn't always a new thread, and (2) multiple requests can come in over one connection, so it isn't a thread per connection either, new or old.

Comment: Can you give a code example for what you are asking? There are some places in web applications where using a `Future` does make sense, but definitely calling `Future.isDone()` in a loop is the wrong way to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread takes up a stack size (preallocated, see -Xss) and too many threads could exhaust memory. It's possibly better to return the thread to the servlet container and use the async capabilities of servlet api 3.1. Otherwise, there isn't any benefit of hanging in future.get() except when your execution service running the task for this future requires to have less threads concurrent than requests concurrent. Ex: 800 servlet connections waiting on a SQL query execution svc of only 50 threads. It could also be about security/authorization, when only threads from a specific executor svc are allowed to perform some sensitive calls (threads created from a thread factory that has privileges).